# Python statistics package(s) for bootstrapping confidence intervals and non-parametric multiple dataset comparisons

Tags: python, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I'm looking for a Python package that can compute either/both bootstrapped confidence intervals and perform non-parametric multiple dataset comparisons. Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the help of my lab mates, I found packages for all the statistics I would need.

Bootstrapped CIs: http://scikits.appspot.com/bootstrap

ANOVA: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html

I hope this is helpful for anyone else who finds themselves in my shoes!

Comment: ANOVA is **parametric**, though; see, e.g., [GraphPad's checklist](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/index.htm?stat_checklist_1wayanova.htm) for the assumptions.  This being said, parametric tests can be used for non-normal data, see, e.g., [Minitab's advice](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/choosing-between-a-nonparametric-test-and-a-parametric-test).

Comment: just fyi http://scikits.appspot.com/bootstrap is a dead link, it is 8 years later though..